# Distance origin to point in the space

Tags: r

I want to equalize the distance from the origin to all points, where points are given by a data frame with two coordinates.

I have all the points as:

```
           x      y
  1      0.0    0.0
  2     -4.0   -2.8
  3     -7.0   -6.5
  4     -9.0  -11.1
  5     -7.7  -16.9
  6     -4.2  -22.4
  7     -0.6  -27.7
  8      3.0  -32.5
  9      5.6  -36.7
  10     8.4  -40.8
```

To get the distance I apply the Euclidean distance for a vector. I have tried this:

```
distance <- function(trip) {
     distance = lapply(trip, function (x) sqrt( (trip[x,]-trip[1,] )^2+ trip[,x]-trip[,1] )^2))
     return(distance)
 }
```

and this as well:

```
distance = apply(trip,1, function (x) sqrt( (trip[x,]-trip[1,] )^2+ (trip[,x]-trip[,1] )^2))
return(distance)
```

Comment: scale the point by `DESIRED_DIST / DIST_FROM_ORIGIN`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to loop through the individual rows of your data with the `apply` function. You can compute all the distances in one shot with vectorized arithmetic in R:

```
(distance <- sqrt((trip$x - trip$x[1])^2 + (trip$y - trip$y[1])^2))
#  [1]  0.000000  4.882622  9.552487 14.290206 18.571484 22.790349 27.706497 32.638168 37.124790 41.655732
```

Computing all the distances at once with vectorized operations will be much quicker in cases where you have many points.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function for matrix distance computation :

```
dist(trip, method = "euclidean")
```

If you don't expect a distance matrix but only the distance from each point to the origin, you can subset the 1st column `as.matrix(dist(mat, method = "euclidean"))[1,]`